# We pose recommendation as extreme multiclass classification problem, what is a class here? is it video category? or the video itself?

Tags: recommender-system, multilabel-classification

In the Youtube video recommendation paper, the author talks about candidate generation is a multi class classification problem, I am trying to understand what the classes here, a video category or the video itself? If it is video category, how did they come up with those categories?

Comment: Please provide a link to the paper and site the exact section you're referring to

Comment: here is the link: https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/45530.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Hot take: Everything is a classification problem.

For video recommendation, think about each row of your data is a person (observation), then each column (feature) is a different video.

This would give us a HUGE dataset, of `(num_users, 800m videos)`.
Clearly V difficult to build a model for, so recommendation is typically broken down into ~3 phases:

1. Recall: Take your set of 800m videos down to some reasonable number. This is typically done with rules-based approaches (think subscriptions, similar users collaborative filtering, clustering etc...). Recently more exotic DNN architectures (transformers) have been used.
2. Ranking: Now we take the smaller set of videos, attach a bunch of features to them (think age of video, length of video, trending etc...) and pass them into a Ranking model. This can be a deep learning ranker, a LightGBBM/XGBoost ranker, a more simple linear model and so on.
3. Post-ranking: General clean up of the results, very domain specific. Maybe we choose this phase to remove harmful content the user has specifically asked not to see - I'm sure there is a better example.

Caveats, I would need to see the actual paper you are talking about - this is a rough framework for modern recommendation engines - **it's one of the most challenging topics in data science**.